# Solving system Ax=b in linear least squares fashion with complex elements and lower-triangular square A matrix

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I would like to solve the linear system `Ax = b` in a linear least squares fashion, thereby obtaining `x`.  Matrices `A`, `x` and `b` contain elements that are complex numbers.

Matrix `A` has dimensions of `n` by `n`, and `A` is a square matrix that is also lower triangular. Vectors `b` and `x` have lengths of `n`.  There are as many unknowns as there are equations in this system, but since `b` is a vector filled with actual measured "data", I suspect that it would be better to do this in a linear least squares fashion.

I am looking for an algorithm that will efficiently solve this system in a LLS fashion, using perhaps a sparse matrix data structure for lower-triangular matrix `A`.

Perhaps there is a C/C++ library with such an algorithm already available?  (I suspect that it is best to use a library due to optimized code.)  Looking around in the Eigen matrix library, it appears that SVD decomposition can be used to solve a system of equations in a LLS fashion ([link to Eigen documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialLinearAlgebra.html#TutorialLinAlgLeastsquares)).  However, how do I work with complex numbers in Eigen?

It appears that the Eigen library works with the SVD, and then uses this for LLS solving.

---

Here is a code snippet demonstrating what I would like to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <complex>

using namespace Eigen;

int main()

{

    // I would like to assign complex numbers
    // to A and b

    /*
    MatrixXcd A(4, 4);
    A(0,0) = std::complex(3,5);     // Compiler error occurs here
    A(1,0) = std::complex(4,4);
    A(1,1) = std::complex(5,3);
    A(2,0) = std::complex(2,2);
    A(2,1) = std::complex(3,3);
    A(2,2) = std::complex(4,4);
    A(3,0) = std::complex(5,3);
    A(3,1) = std::complex(2,4);
    A(3,2) = std::complex(4,3);
    A(3,3) = std::complex(2,4);
    */

    // The following code is taken from:
    // http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialLinearAlgebra.html#TutorialLinAlgLeastsquares

    // This is what I want to do, but with complex numbers
    // and with A as lower triangular

    MatrixXf A = MatrixXf::Random(3, 3);
    std::cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << std::endl;
    VectorXf b = VectorXf::Random(3);
    std::cout << "Here is the right hand side b:\n" << b << std::endl;
    std::cout << "The least-squares solution is:\n"
    << A.jacobiSvd(ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV).solve(b) << std::endl;
}// end
```

Here is the compiler error:

```
 error: missing template arguments before '(' token
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is an updated program showing how to deal with the LLS solving using Eigen.  This code does indeed compile correctly.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <Eigen/Dense>

#include <complex>


using namespace Eigen;


int main()

{

    MatrixXcd A(4, 4);
    A(0,0) = std::complex<double>(3,5);
    A(1,0) = std::complex<double>(4,4);
    A(1,1) = std::complex<double>(5,3);
    A(2,0) = std::complex<double>(2,2);
    A(2,1) = std::complex<double>(3,3);
    A(2,2) = std::complex<double>(4,4);
    A(3,0) = std::complex<double>(5,3);
    A(3,1) = std::complex<double>(2,4);
    A(3,2) = std::complex<double>(4,3);
    A(3,3) = std::complex<double>(2,4);

    VectorXcd b(4);
    b(0) = std::complex<double>(3,5);
    b(1) = std::complex<double>(2,0);
    b(2) = std::complex<double>(8,2);
    b(3) = std::complex<double>(4,8);

        std::cout << "Here is the A matrix:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << A << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Here is the b vector:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << b << std::endl;

    std::cout << "The least-squares solution is:\n"

        << A.jacobiSvd(ComputeThinU | ComputeThinV).solve(b) << std::endl;


}// end
```

Comment: and what line does that error refer to?

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: The line refers to `A(0,0) = std::complex(3,5);`, and the assignments of object type `std::complex`.

Comment: Can you show what  MatrixXcd is?

Comment: Wait, your matrix is already a lower-triangular matrix? Why don't you simply use [forward and back substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution)?

Comment: @AntonRoth: Apparently it is a matrix of complex elements in Eigen.  It is a convenience typedef (see bottom of page): http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMatrixClass.html.

Comment: @Zeta: Perhaps it is good to use forward and back substitution? However, since `b` is "real" data, perhaps a linear-least squares solution would be better to use?  The forward-back substitution might be beneficial to use if the system of equations is simply "mathematical" and does not deal with "actual" data?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to use std::complex<double>(2,4); instead?

Comment: @AntonRoth: Ah yes - that does indeed work!  Now the compile error disappears.  I will investigate more and write some additional code, and then update my question above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `std::complex` is a template class, and you init with `std::complex(1,1);` the compiler doesn't know what type it is.

Use `std::complex<double>(1, 1);` instead.

Comment: Thank you; you are right about the compiler not knowing the type of the object.