# How to solve complex linear systems?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have a complex matrix A and a complex vector b. I would like to solve the linear system Ax=b.
I tried to use the example on this page, and adapt it to my complex problem. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialLinearAlgebra.html

Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

My objects are defined this way:

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<complexd, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> DoubleComplexMatrix;
typedef Eigen::Array<complexd, Eigen::Dynamic, 1> DoubleComplexArray;
```

And in my code I want to solve this

```
   DoubleComplexMatrix A(3,3);
   DoubleComplexArray b(3);
   DoubleComplexArray x(3);

   A << 1,2,3,  4,5,6,  7,8,10;
   b << 3, 3, 4;
   cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
   cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;

   ColPivHouseholderQR<DoubleComplexMatrix> dec(A);
   x = dec.solve(b);
   cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
```

The error appears at the line: `DoubleComplexArray x = dec.solve(b);` because when I comment it, there is no more error.

I get this error:

```
TideSolve.cpp:98:38: error: no matching function for call to ‘Eigen::ColPivHouseholderQR<Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<double>, -1, -1> >::solve(DoubleComplexArray&)’
DoubleComplexArray x = dec.solve(b);
```

Does that mean that eigen solvers does not work with complex? (I'm sure they do, and I'm just bad!)
Do I need another solver than `ColPivHouseholderQR` that work with complex? If so, which one?

I have found [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13747290) where someone used another solver.

Comment: I've removed the "Please help" and "Apologies for my English".  a) They aren't relevant; b) Your English is fine; better I suspect than a significant number of native English speakers who post here.

Comment: Your sample code shows:  `DoubleComplexArray x(3);` + `x = dec.solve(b);`.  Your error message and text shows `DoubleComplexArray x = dec.solve(b);`.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Eigen::Matrix` instead of `Eigen::Array`. The later is for raw 2D array of values. The former is for linear algebra matrices and vectors. See the respective [manual page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialArrayClass.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It fixed my problem. But I have to admit it is pretty slow. It took 2hours to solve a 1800*1800 matrix. Do you think it is a normal time ? I compile using : g++ -o  main  *.cpp

Comment: Don't forget to enable compiler's optimizations with the `-O3` flag. It then should be several order of magnitude faster. Since your problem is square, if you know that it is invertible, then using `PartialPivLU` will provide much speed up too. It then should be of the order of 1s.